# Deploying for iOS3.1.3 using Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios

Just upgraded to Xcode 4.2 and am trying to figure out how to compile an app for iOS3.

I've set the deployment target as iOS3 but am getting this build error:
ld: library not found for -lz.1.2.3
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

I assume this is a library that has been added but not sure where to find this option in Xcode nor how I solve it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting compile error because the compiler cannot find your library but not because it cannot compile for iOS 3.

You are doing right at the deployment target part.

Try use `libz.dylib` instead of the one with version fixed in its filename, see if it resolved the compile error.

Comment: Given the error the original poster mentioned in the question, I'm pretty sure this is the right answer - it's a problem I've had too! If you swap out the current libz library for the newer one with XCode 4.2 you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Apple removed support for `arm6` processors (= `<= iOS 3`) in Xcode 4.2.

Comment: So does that mean installing two versions of Xcode to support iOS3 AND iOS5?

Comment: Basically, yes. I'm running both Xcode 3 (in `/Developer Old/`) and Xcode 4.2 (in `/Developer/`) so I can support all the iOS versions (`>= 3.0`).

Comment: iOS 3 doesn't mean armv6 only. iOS 3 can also support armv7 if it's running on a iPhone 3GS.

Comment: I think by default, now, arm6 is not included in a project's supported architectures. But you can add arm6 back in to the list of supported architectures in the build settings for a project.... no? I had to do this recently for an app that support iOS3.0.

Comment: Xuzhe's answer is the correct one - XCode 4.2 contains a new version of the libz library, but the project is referencing the old one. YOu can just replace the library with the newer version to fix it.